# Server Side Caching Strategies for jQuery auto-complete?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am in the process of implementing several tagging fields on my website that include an autocomplete option using the jquery UI plugin.  I have everything working, and while the widget itself isn't as robust as I would prefer (is there a way to make the first item in the list always highlighted, for instance), it is serviceable for now.

My question is around handling the server-side requests for the autocomplete data.  Right now I'm using AJAX to retrieve the potential matches for the supplied input term.  The table I'm hitting has around 10,000 records in it, and my thought was that rather than constantly querying that table, I could just cache a list of those records in a shared/static property on my server (I'm using ASP.NET MVC with a SQL Server backend by the way) and query that list instead.  I would refresh the list every 4 hours or so, just to keep it up to date.

The idea is obviously to reduce the strain on my SQL server and maximize the performance of the autocomplete drop down.  **What I'm ultimately wondering is if it's bad practice to keep a list/array of 10,000 values in memory on my server; is there a known limit/threshold here?**  My server has 2GB of RAM, and may need to be upgraded soon anyway.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have a performance problem now?  Is the query a simple Where something like 'asdf%'?  How often is this dropdown hit?  Sounds like you are optimizing performance without a reason to optimize performance.

Comment: Would you agree that almost users won't search for all 10,000 values in all their life ? I suggest to create the cache each time user search for a certain letter, or phrase. By a week, your server can create a "most-searched" list. The number of cached records may be a kid compared to 10,000. If user searchs for a rare keyword, they need to wait some more milliseconds for server to create new cache. Such a flexible strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10,000 small strings shouldn't be too bad - I've done that before with no noticeable side effects.

I would recommend running your app without the items in memory, and then again with, and take a look at memory and CPU usage in Task Manager in Windows, just to get an idea of how much memory you truly are using up - that will help determine if it will cause problems down the road.

But hitting the database each time probably wouldn't be that bad either - unless you hae a ton of traffic, the effect would likely be negligible.

Comment: I published this update over the weekend and thus far the performance hit doesn't seem to be that bad.  I've only had a few users utilize the system thus far, but as far as I can tell I'm using an additional 30-50MB of memory than before the update (however I also added a number of other things that I'm storing in the session, so that could explain some of it as well).

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use the [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) attribute provided by asp.net mvc. Its better than storing them in memory, just let the framework handle it for you.

You can easily set your timeout, etc.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I wasn't aware of this attribute, but it's something i can give some thought to.  I'll let you know if I end up going that route.  Thanks for the suggestion!